# TestNg Annotation - @AfterMethod does not run

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, annotations

I have 2 methods to be run in TestNg framework but my code executes only @Test and @AfterMethod does not execute.

[image: code Screenshot is as per below]

Please find output of result. As you can see, only AdminLogin method run and Closebrowser method failed and did not provide any result due to that it skipped other 2 test.

[image]

Comment: Try `@AfterMethoid(alwaysRun = true)` annotation.

Comment: hi, I tried and it is running but the error is now :: 
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod closebrowser
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Try to set priority and run

Comment: Yes, because it seems like you aren't quitting the driver that you have initialized during the test. I can see a driver object is newly created in test (Local scope).

Comment: I have to try 3 different username and pass to try out and each time i have to load a new browser... due to that, either i can quite or close driver. If i use the same command with If condition line number 36, it works fine as expected only with the method it doesnt work.

Comment: with the AfterMethod() it is not allowing to set the priority in this program

Comment: @SushantTavrawala you can try something like `driver = new ChromeDriver()` in line 28. Instead of `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()`

Comment: Mate you are legend.... :) ... that solve the problem... epic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

Instead of trying to create a new Object, just initialize it everytime ion all the methods.
So, instead of doing

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Try using

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Also, for the @AfterMethod you can use annotation:

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
```